# How CONNECT BY in subquery works

Tags: oracle

I have a query as below

```
select substr( 'ORACLE DEVELOPER',level,1 ) ITEM
from dual connect by level <= length('ORACLE DEVELOPER') ;
```

it returns 'O' as the result.

but if i put this as a subquery in other it is displaying the required output.
query is as below.

```
select a.ITEM from (select substr( 'ORACLE DEVELOPER',level,1 ) ITEM
from dual connect by level <= length('ORACLE DEVELOPER') ) a
```

How this CONNECT BY is working in subquery.
I am new to this feature. Can anyone explain this??

Comment: Both produce same [result](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/25887).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does a connect by expression in a FOR loop, execute only once?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22815549/why-does-a-connect-by-expression-in-a-for-loop-execute-only-once)

Answer (score 2):

CONNECT BY is Oracle SQL syntax for doing hierarchical queries. Some good examples are [here](http://psoug.org/reference/connectby.html).

One of the side effects is that it allows you to query a single data source multiple times, which means that there's a handy trick to generate any number of rows with:

```
SELECT 1
FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10;
```

The above will connect dual back to itself 10 times - the `LEVEL` pseudocolumn is from the hierarchy; because the CONNECT BY clause doesn't actually refer to any data from the rowsource, it effectively makes dual its own child, grandchild, great-grandchild, etc. until the CONNECT BY clause evaluates to false (in this case, when LEVEL becomes greater than 10).

In your case, you are generating a row for each letter of the string (instead of 10, you are referring to LENGTH('a string'), which is a nice way of getting a query to return one record for each letter in the string. You are then using SUBSTR to pick out the nth letter from the string.